# Сервис отключается при засыпании телефона

Tags: java, android, service

Код сервиса, который каждую минуту запускает вибрацию на телефоне.
Как только экран гаснет, сервис прекращает работу. Как запретить остановку? И как в нужный момент по кнопке остановить этот сервис?

```
    public class TimeService extends Service {
Vibrator vib;
public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000; // 60 seconds
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Timer mTimer = null;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; }

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    vib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    // cancel if already existed
    if (mTimer != null) { mTimer.cancel();}
else { mTimer = new Timer(); }
    // schedule task
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0,
            NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
}

class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                vib.vibrate(500);
            }
        });
    }
```

Запускаю сервис так:

```
public void onClick_btTask(View v) {
    startService(new Intent(this, TimeService.class));

}
```

Comment: а вы уверены, что это сервис засыпает, а не, например, вибрировать с выключенным экраном запрещено, или типа того?

Comment: А как это определить?

Comment: добавьте логи, или еще что-то возле ` vib.vibrate(500);`

Comment: @metalurgus интересно, а как вибрируют приложения, посылая уведомления в шторку? Вам не кажется, что в таких случаях экран обычно тоже выключен?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service по умолчанию работает в том же потоке, что и запускающая его activity. Чтобы вибрировать каждую минуту, можете попробовать использовать связку с IntentService и AlarmManager-а с ключом RTC_WAKEUP, который будет этот IntentService каждую минуту вызывать. Примерно так:

```
public class VibrateService extends IntentService {
    public static final String TAG = "VibrateService";

    public VibrateService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(500);
    }
}
```

...

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, VibrateService.class);

    // Запуск повторения вызова сервиса
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60 * 1000,
            PendingIntent.getService(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Конечно же, VibrateService должен быть объявлен в манифесте, как и разрешение вибрировать: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`